# libssl undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_load_error_strings@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'

Tags: make, libraries, ssl, dynamic-linking, cmake

With the following CMakeLists.txt (I tried to snip it AMAP)

https://gist.github.com/pbertoni/29200833dc562ab6ee2c

I got this error from `make` at linking time:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/blockmon.dir/bin/blockmon.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_load_error_strings@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/blockmonWithXmlRPC.dir/bin/blockmonWithXmlRPC.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_load_error_strings@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For each of the two executables which Cmake is targeting. Output of:

```
ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc5a1f4000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fad78c52000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fad7888d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fad78688000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fad792bd000)
```

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS x64`. Note that on a `Debian 7.8 x64` system **it works**!

I'v tried to snip the executable code at this gist.

https://gist.github.com/pbertoni/7c82c12683d4491339c1

Comment: So, what are you trying to compile and why? Is the software in question not packaged for your distribution?

Comment: I'm compiling a copyrighted program which I'm afraid I cannot provide. Program is not packaged, I got sources, few external libs and CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Well, try to reduce your problem down to a reproducible working example, and then post that. What distribution are you using?

Comment: Added some information. But please be patient, I suppose you need something more from that headers..

Comment: Ok, please edit the question to include your example. You don't need to put it on another site. It is quite short.

Comment: I get `fatal error: CompositionManager.hpp: No such file or directory` when I try to compile. You're going to need a self-contained example. I suggest bundling your code with a build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers removed that symbol. See https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/72257204bd2a88773461150765dfd0e0a428ee86/include/openssl/ssl.h#L1495 What you need to do is add `#define OPENSSL_API_COMPAT 0x0908` somewhere to get the symbol defined as a macro.

Comment: Hi Bjorn, do you know if the issue is the same also for the function SSL_get_verify_result@@OPENSSL_1_1_0?